# foreach (#file in $files){ nul find "2019" $file save(D:\Export2019\$file) }

Tags: powershell

.ps1 copy files to a specific locations if specific text in file

i`m trying a code in Powershell ...
I have a lot of .xml files in S:\Export\ and i want to copy the files that contains the text "2019" in the folder S:\Export2019\

This is my code:

```
Start-Transcript -Path S:\Export2019\info.txt
$files = Get-ChildItem "S:\Export\"
mkdir S:\Export2019
foreach ($file in $files){
>nul find "<APPDATE>2019" $file (
  echo $file was found.
  Save("S:\Export2019\$file")
) 
}
ii S:\Export2019 #
```

I have a lot of .xml files in S:\Export\ and i want to copy the files that contains the text "2019" in the folder S:\Export2019\

this is not working:

```
>nul find "<APPDATE>2019" $file (
  echo $file was found.
  Save("S:\Export2019\$file")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if I understood your question correctly. The following script will loop through all XML-files in a specific directory and searches for the text `2019`. If that text is in the file, it will be copied into another directory

Please be aware that this script is a very rough and "brute force" approach but it should give you a basis to work with

```
$source_dir = ".\S_Export2019" # Directory where the XML files are
$target_dir = ".\Target_Directory" # Directory where "2019" files will be copied to

# Loop through the directory $source_dir and get the fullpath of all XML-files
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem "$source_dir\*.xml")) {
    # Save the content of the XML file
    $file_content = Get-Content $file -raw

    # Check if the XML file contains "2019"
    if ($file_content -match "2019") {
        Write-Host "$file contains '2019'"
        Copy-Item $file $target_dir # Copy file to $target_dir
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Thanks @LotPings for the correction - I've added the `-raw` Parameter to the `Get-Content` and also changed the `if`-comparison to use `-match` rather than the former `-contains`

Comment: you understood correct , the code is ok , in my opinion , but it does not copy the files ... :(

Comment: Add the -raw parameter to `Get-Content` and change `-contains` => `-match`

Comment: Thanks @LotPings - I've added your corrections in the above snippet